# How to call an Apex Class and method using Type casting?

Tags: apex, trigger, interface, type

I would like to call `someMethod1` and `someMethod2` from `myClass` from a Trigger on update. How can I use type casting to call the two methods?

myInterfaceClass

```
public interface myInterfaceClass {
  void someMethod1();
  void someMethod2();
}
```

myClass class

```
public class myClass implements myInterfaceClass {
  public static void someMethod1() { /* code logic */ }
  public static void someMethod2() { /* code logic */ }  
}
```

**Here is what i tried but not sure it is correct**

myTrigger class

```
trigger myTrigger on Contact (after update) {
  Type myType = Type.forName('myClass');
  myType.someMethod1();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast your variable type. The class that implements that interface should be cast to that interface, so you can access its methods:

```
 IMyInterface instance = (IMyInterface) Type.forName('Myclass');
 instance.someMethod1();
```